# On Error Resume Next Not Working

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So I have created a rather large macro which creates powerpoint presentations for my company. I would like to be able to run it for 2 different regions using:

```
For each sRegion

MyMacro(sRegion)

Next
```

There are some lines I would like to skip. For the first run MyMacro works perfectly and the error handler skips the steps. However for the next sRegion the error handler doesn't work.

Even if I run through it line by line going through the on error resume next statement it doesn't work and actually just stops the macro.

I'll post the code where it is breaking, though it is completely irrelevant (on a second run through, works fine when the macro is called first)

```
On Error Resume Next

PPPres.Slides(19).Moveto ToPos:=12
PPPres.Slides(20).Moveto ToPos:=13
PPPres.Slides(21).Moveto ToPos:=14
PPPres.Slides(22).Moveto ToPos:=15
PPPres.Slides(23).Moveto ToPos:=16

On Error GoTo 0
```

It will completely disregard the on error and throw up an error and stop the macro.

Before anyone suggests yes I have checked whether Error Trapping is on 'Break on Unhandled Errors' and it is

Anyone had this issue before or know a solution?

Comment: How do you define an `sRegion`?

Comment: Why would that matter? This is only about the error trapping

Comment: Errors come from inputs.  If we can figure out your input error, you can correct the crash.  Typically, the syntax for For Each is `For Each something In Collection of somethings`

Comment: well it is a range so its for each sRegion in .Range("R1:R100") but again that shouldn't make any difference to the error trapping

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` isn't error trapping - it's error ignoring. Why don't you have a `GoTo` label for error trapping and test the `Err.Number` to decide on which action to take - then clear the error accordingly. In the first instance I'd run the code without the `On Error` statement to see if it produced the same error. Also - what is the error that you're getting?

Comment: I know it's error ignoring, I don't think you really understand my issue. I know what the error is if I use a label which I do elsewhere in the code it won't work either. The point is, instead of using ANY on error and either going to a label or just going next, vba won't do it. This has nothing to do with the error or nature of the error it is just why vba is deciding to ignore my statement

Comment: I don't think there's enough context in this post to answer your question, ...whatever that question might be. Voting to close as *unclear what you're asking* - context is **not** irrelevant, please include enough code so we can know what you're talking about. Help us help you!

Comment: I can't post all the code though. Theres 6 huge modules and this issue occurs quite randomly. It will just break the error handlers will just stop working and errors will break the macro instead of jumping to the error handlers. I only posted in the small hope that someone would've had a similar issue as I can't fin anything on the net about it

Comment: The point is, it's not clear what your question is. It seems you're wondering why `On Error Resume Next` is completely disregarding any error...

Comment: I think ultimately the issue is that you are assuming that you know what the problem is, and in actual fact it probably has nothing to do with the `On Error` statement. Code can't decide when it wants to work - every line is compiled and executed exactly when it has been designed to. This would suggest your issue is elsewhere

Comment: I promise you I'm not assuming I know what the problem is. I very much don't. I just don't understand how if I go line by line over an on error statement it will still throw up an error? Surely that is something someone can help me with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Be sure that after jumping on error (you used `On Error GoTo`) you remove error condition by using `Resume` or `Resume Next` or `Resume <label>` command.** Or alternatively, remove that `On Error GoTo`, use only `On Error Resume Next`.

Based on your question and comments you are doing the following, what **always throws error** at second statement:

```
Sub WrongOne()
  On Error Goto Handler1    'prepared for error
    Statement1WithError()   'error causes jump

  Handler1:                 'jump done, error handling is now disabled
    Statement2WithError()   'THIS WILL ALWAYS THROW ERROR
End Sub
```

You will always get error on `Statement2WithError()`

**Correct way:**

```
Sub CorrectOne()

  On Error Goto Handler1    '1. prepared for error
    Statement1WithError()   '2. error causes jump

  Waypoint1:                '5. continuing here
  On Error Goto Handler2    '6. prepared for another error

    Statement2WithError()   '7. error causes jump to Handler2
    Statement3WithError()   '10. error causes jump to Handler2
    Statement4WithError()   'etc... 

Exit Sub

                           'EXAMPLE: after error, continue at SPECIFIC LABEL
Handler1:                  '3. jump done, error handling is now disabled
  MsgBox(...)
  Resume Waypoint1         '4. error handling is reloaded, jumping to label

                           'EXAMPLE: after error, continue with NEXT LINE
Handler2:                  '8. jump done, error handling is now disabled
  MsgBox(...)
  Resume Next              '9. error handling is reloaded, now jumping to line
                           '   following the line that caused error

End Sub
```

In your case, VBA is working as expected. You can study [how error handling works in VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141571/en-us).

Comment: You can try `On Error Resume` Next without any `On Error Goto` (or with correctly Resumed handler) so execution will fly through all errors. Optionally you can conditionally skip sections of code if you can detect error condition in advance. (`If Slides.Count < 25 Then GoTo Label2`)  Another approach is to be selective about code:  `Dim Region = 1 : If Region < 2 Then 'code for first 2 regions End If: If Region = 2 Then 'code for second region only' etc.  Then change `Dim Region = x` before launch of code. Or use  InputBox() to get it.

Comment: It has helped but there are still other issues now which I will come back to once I've got a better overview of what is happening. Apologies for no code but I don't understand how I'm supposed to post huge amounts of code and how that can be helpful?

Comment: Feel free to ask another questions. Regarding the code passages, get some feeling which sequences are not important and condense them to e.g. `SomeCommandsHere()`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70863/discussion-on-answer-by-miroxlav-on-error-resume-next-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

Look at what happens here:

```
    On Error Resume Next

' Error here, but we're ignoring it
' because of On Error Resume Next:
    PPPres.Slides(19).Moveto ToPos:=12
' No more errors from here on:
    PPPres.Slides(20).Moveto ToPos:=13
    PPPres.Slides(21).Moveto ToPos:=14
    PPPres.Slides(22).Moveto ToPos:=15
    PPPres.Slides(23).Moveto ToPos:=16
' But the err condition is still set ... you haven't cleared it,
' so when we get here, it throws the error:    
    On Error GoTo 0
```

It sounds as though on the first iteration, everything's going fine, but something's throwing an error the second time through.  I'd comment out the On Error Resume Next and step through the code to see where it stops with an error.